# Find out which row of table you've just moved

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to make a table with dragabble and droppable rows which I can achieve with jquery ui, however I then want to update the number in first cell in each row to always correspond to the numerical order from the top down.

For example the table might start out like this:

```
<table id="myTableId">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="draggable droppable"><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
        <tr class="draggable droppable"><td>2</td><td>def</td></tr>
        <tr class="draggable droppable"><td>3</td><td>ghi</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

After the user has dragged the rows about it may end up like this for example:

```
<table id="myTableId">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="draggable droppable"><td>2</td><td>def</td></tr>
        <tr class="draggable droppable"><td>3</td><td>ghi</td></tr>
        <tr class="draggable droppable"><td>1</td><td>abc</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I then want to run a function to sort numbers in the first cells back into numerical order from the top down so that the html would change to look like this:

```
<table id="myTableId">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="draggable droppable"><td>1</td><td>def</td></tr>
        <tr class="draggable droppable"><td>2</td><td>ghi</td></tr>
        <tr class="draggable droppable"><td>3</td><td>abc</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The rows have been moved but the row at the top still has the value 1 in the first cell, the second row still has the value 2 and so on...

I have found a JavaScript a function which counts the number of rows in a table, how can I write a JavaScript function to reorder the numbers 1,2 and 3 back into sequence in the first cells in the table?

```
<script>
    var rows = document.getElementById('myTableId').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr').length;
    alert(rows);
</script>
```

For reference this is the jquery I am using to make the rows draggable and droppable:

```
$(function() {

    $(".draggable").draggable( {
        helper: function() { return "<div class='shadow'></div>"; },
        start: moveShadow,
        revert: true
     });

    function moveShadow(event, ui) {
        var helper = ui.helper;
        var element = $(event.target);
        helper.width(element.width());
        helper.height(element.height());
    }

    $(".droppable").droppable({
        hoverClass: 'ui-state-active',
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var target = $(event.target);
            var draggable = ui.draggable;
            draggable.insertBefore(target);
          }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to count anything. Just run a loop and increment:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/tLpjho9f/

```
var myCount = 1;

$('#myTableId tr.droppable').each(function() {
    $(this).find('td').eq(0).text(myCount);
    myCount ++;
});
```

You'll want to work that into the drop callback.

Comment: That worked, just had to call that and pass myCount as 1 each time so that it started at 1 each time. Thanks :)